# Can I get couchbase to work in class library as opposed to just my webapp

Tags: c#, couchbase

I have the following setup for my project:

```
MyProject.WebApp (dependent on MyProject.Domain)
MyProject.Domain
```

Inside my webapp I have the routine setup for couchbase and it works successfully (for example, if i put a simple get set in one of my controllers it works fine), but when I try to do the code in my class lib (`MyProject.Domain`) it does not connect successfully.  I have tried to develop a class in my class lib that looks like this:

```
public static class CouchbaseManager
    {
        private  static CouchbaseClient _instance;

        static CouchbaseManager()
        {
            _instance = new CouchbaseClient(); 
        }

        public static CouchbaseClient Instance { get { return _instance; } }
    }
```

In my `Global.asax` of my webapp I try to initialize this `CouchbaseManager` so i can use it in my class library, but no luck.  I have added an `app.config` file to my class lib as well with all the correct settings.  Can this be done?

Comment: Is there an error when you try it the other way? If you just initialize the `CouchbaseClient` with a `CouchbaseClientSection`, does that work?

Comment: Why don't you want to declare this CouchbaseManager class as sealed and implement singleton pattern based on `Lazy` class.

`public sealed class CouchbaseManager {
private static readonly Lazy<CouchbaseManager> _lazy = new Lazy<CouchbaseManager>(() => new CouchbaseManager());
public CouchbaseClient Client;
private CouchbaseRepo()
        {
            Client = new CouchbaseClient(CouchbaseConfig.getBucketConfigSection("bucketname"));
        }
        public static CouchbaseManager Instance { get { return _lazy.Value; } }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your specific error it's hard to say. Your class library, if referenced correctly, would live with the web app and so you would not need the app.config, the details in web.config should suffice: the section declaration and the couchbase section populated with your database details.

Check also if the library is setup to use the full .net version as it cannot run under the ".NET Framework Client Profile".

Personaly I would create another project for your data access layer and have your web app and domain library access it, you will have a better design that way and avoid having 2 instances of couchbase client which is not recommended.